# nginx exclude path from https

Tags: php, ssl, redirect, nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to exclude path **client** and every url that contains **client** from https, using nginx.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;


        location / {
                return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }

        location /client/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}

server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;


        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';


        root /var/www/laravel/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location /client/ {
                return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;

        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
                expires 30d;
                add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
                access_log off;
        }
}
```

*I removed ssl certificate key from second server block.*

When i type https://example.com/client, i get redirected to http://www.example.com/client (as expected). I have a simple index.php file inside client folder that is not getting executed. I am seeing too many redirects in browser.

Comment: You are missing `root` and `index` statements in the first `server` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks a lot! I have been testing all day, and i was looking for redirect issue.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith

Added root and index statements in first server block.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        root /var/www/laravel/public; #LINE-ADDED

        index index.php index.html index.htm; #LINE-ADDED

        # other code here ...
}
```